# C++/CLI Start-up code

Tags: c++-cli, startup

I need to write a program for my computer to run at startup, and its doing fine. **However**, I need the program to `hide();` when it starts up, so my friends don't see it open up. I am currently using `Microsoft Visual C++`. I've tried placing the code in many places of my project, which includes:

- the `Form1(void)` thingy, right below `InitializeComponent();`
- inside the `void InitializeComponent(void)` thingy
- inside the `#pragma endregion` thingy

**BUT TO NO AVAIL!!!**

Can anyone please tell me where to put the start-up code? I basically just tried putting

- `hide();`
  and
- `HWND findwindow` or whatever it is :/

...into my code.

I would appreciate any help available. I am also willing to take examples and substitutions for my code. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds malicious.. Why do you want to do this again?

Comment: Ok, the point of this project is to launch my web stream so I can see what my dogs are doing when I leave the house. The project is basically opening my USTREAM webpage and broadcasting through my webcam. However, I want this to be "hush-hush" so nobody goes into my room to mess with the webcam. Can anyone give me suggestions or examples? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does this even necessarily need a UI to work? It sounds like something you could achieve with a Windows service.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, it requires a UI so I can check the broadcast settings. My C++ project is to have it opened and streaming while hidden. The UI also allows me to see the controls ONLY when I open it, it's hidden in the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK everyone, I know what I have to do. I Googled this for days and finally... I just have to put the line on the `Load` thingy on the properties window. That's it! So simple but I missed it...

Thanks, though!